# How to make an indexable array of collections

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing, collections

I am parsing multiple data files from various tests I ran, and I want to group the values from each test in variables belonging to collections.  For example a pair of the collections is:

```
type_GA_RX1 = collections.namedtuple('type_GA_RX1',
                                    ['GA_RX1',
                                    'GA_RX1logmag',
                                    'GA_RX1mag',
                                    'GA_RX1ph'])

type_GA_RX2 = collections.namedtuple('type_GA_RX2',
                                        ['GA_RX2',
                                        'GA_RX2logmag',
                                        'GA_RX2mag',
                                        'GA_RX2ph'])
```

I want to do something like this as I iterate through the files:

```
keys=dataGA.keys()   # dictionary of parsed file data 
for key in keys:
        if len(dataGA[key]) >0:
            GA_RX1logmag   = np.array(dataGA[key].RX1_log_mag)
            GA_RX1mag      = 10**(GA_RX1logmag/20)
            GA_RX1         = np.array(dataGA[key].RX1_real +1j*dataGA[key].RX1_imag)
            GA_RX1ph       = np.array(dataGA[key].RX1_phase)
```

and then assign these to the collection type:

```
type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1logmag =  GA_RX1logmag
type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1mag    =  GA_RX1mag
type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1       =  GA_RX1
type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1ph     =  GA_RX1ph
```

However, I can't index into a 'type' object; I get this error:

```
type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1logmag=  GA_RX1logmag
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I do this?  Or, is this not what I want to do? How do I create an array of collections?

For clarity, `dataGA` looks like this (excerpt):

```
    {0:      RX1_real  RX1_imag  RX2_real  ...  distance  RX2_log_mag  RX1_log_mag
 61  -0.019780 -0.005127  0.010010  ...       1.0   -38.426806   -33.793076
 62  -0.018310 -0.010740  0.007812  ...       4.0   -38.190809   -33.462052
 63  -0.016600 -0.012450  0.006348  ...       8.0   -38.523323   -33.659638
 64  -0.020510 -0.005127  0.010010  ...      18.0   -38.426806   -33.497447
 65  -0.015140 -0.013670  0.005127  ...      25.0   -38.488333   -33.808143
 ..        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...          ...          ...
 477 -0.006104 -0.018310 -0.009521  ...    9795.0   -37.416049   -34.288563
 478 -0.008545  0.017820  0.013180  ...    9799.0   -37.482664   -34.083018
 479  0.000000  0.019290  0.010990  ...    9802.0   -37.584010   -34.293355
 495  0.018800  0.004395 -0.005127  ...    9803.0   -36.574736   -34.285753
 480 -0.008301 -0.017330 -0.007324  ...    9804.0   -37.062341   -34.326965
 
 [401 rows x 9 columns],
 1:      RX1_real  RX1_imag  RX2_real  ...  distance  RX2_log_mag  RX1_log_mag
 61  -0.019780 -0.005127  0.010010  ...       1.0   -38.426806   -33.793076
 62  -0.018310 -0.010740  0.007812  ...       4.0   -38.190809   -33.462052
 63  -0.016600 -0.012450  0.006348  ...       8.0   -38.523323   -33.659638
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1logmag =  GA_RX1logmag
> type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1mag    =  GA_RX1mag
> type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1       =  GA_RX1
> type_GA_RX1[key].GA_RX1ph     =  GA_RX1ph
> ```

There are two or three problems here:

1. You never create an *instance* of `type_GA_RX1`.
2. If you did create one, namedtuple instances are immutable, so you cannot assign attributes after creating them. You need to pass the values directly to the initializer.
3. You seem to try to use `type_GA_RX1[key]` as if `type_GA_RX1` was a dictionary, but you didn't create a dictionary anywhere.
4. I also suspect that you do not actually want to put an entire array of values into one `type_GA_RX1` instance, but only a single value.

I think you meant the following:

```
GA_RX1_instances = {}

for key, data in dataGA.items():
    if len(data) > 0:
        logmag = data.RX1_log_mag
        GA_RX1_instances[key] = type_GA_RX1(
            GA_RX1logmag = logmag
            GA_RX1mag    = 10**(logmag/20)
            GA_RX1       = data.RX1_real + 1j*data.RX1_imag
            GA_RX1ph     = data.RX1_phase
        )
```

where `GA_RX1logmag = ...`, etc., are not local variables, but keyword arguments.

Comment: thanks for responding -- I'm not a s/w guy, so please bear with me.   I thought I was creating the instance in the first code block above.  ---Ah, wait, I see what you did there....let me try that.  Thank you.

Comment: I think I do want to whole array....I want to be able to plot this data, for each run; ie, something like (in pseudo code) "plot(file1.distance,file1.GA_RX1mag), plot(file2.distance,file2.GA_RX1mag)" etc....

Comment: Then I think a dictionary of namedtuples is not the data structure you want. Maybe a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: I was thinking I could use the `collections.namedtuple` as structures for each group of related values (RX1, RX2, etc) and could then use array of structures.  This would then enable me  pass the whole structures (or even the array of structures) to different functions as needed.  again, I'm not a s/w guy, so perhaps I'm not saying the right things.  If I use the pandas.dataframe, I lose the grouping of related values into a common structure.